# How do I return a pane?

Tags: java, javafx

I am almost done with this here program. It is one of them work order forms with event handlers and an updated total. How may I return a total value updated after receiving user input? I am sure I need a return pane somewhere, just not sure where. Code below:

```
public class Working_order extends Application {

    // Radio buttons
    private RadioButton rbNext = new RadioButton("$20");
    private RadioButton rbThis = new RadioButton("$12");
    private RadioButton rbSome = new RadioButton("$5");

    private Label lbDue = new Label("$0.00");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Create a pane and set its properties
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();

        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5));
        pane.setHgap(5.5);
        pane.setVgap(5.5);

        // Place nodes in the pane
        pane.add(new Label("Item"), 0, 0);
        pane.add(tfItem, 1, 0);
        pane.add(new Label("Price"), 0, 1);
        pane.add(tfPrice, 1, 1);
        pane.add(new Label("Quantity"), 0, 2);
        pane.add(tfQty, 1, 2);

        CheckBox chTaxable = new CheckBox("Taxable?");

        pane.add(chTaxable, 1, 3);
        // More nodes in a pane
        pane.add(new Label("Shipping"), 0, 4);
        pane.add(rbNext, 1, 5);
        pane.add(new Label("Next Day"), 0, 5);
        pane.add(rbThis, 1, 6);
        pane.add(new Label("This Week"), 0, 6);
        pane.add(rbSome, 1, 7);
        pane.add(new Label("Total Due"), 0, 8);
        pane.add(lbDue, 1, 8);
        pane.add(new Label("Some Day"), 0, 7);

        Button btAdd = new Button("Process");
        Button btAdd2 = new Button("Reset");

        // Toggle group
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        rbNext.setToggleGroup(group);
        rbThis.setToggleGroup(group);
        rbSome.setToggleGroup(group);

        btAdd.setOnAction(e -> {
            // read textboxes

            String sPrice = tfPrice.getText();
            double price = Double.parseDouble(sPrice);
            int qty = Integer.parseInt(tfQty.getText());
            double subTotal = price * qty;
            double tax;
            if (chTaxable.isSelected()) {
                tax = subTotal * 0.07;
            } else {
                tax = 0;
            }

        });

        pane.add(btAdd, 0, 9);
        pane.add(btAdd2, 1, 9);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btAdd, HPos.RIGHT);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btAdd2, HPos.LEFT);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ShowGridPane"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you "could" use an observer which would be notified when the state changes, but since you're already making the changes in the action handler, why not just update the `lbDue` label directly?

Comment: Not sure how. like pane.add?

Comment: Since you've already done `pane.add(lbDue, 1, 8);` the label is already on the panel.  You just need to update it's text value

Comment: Hmm. Kind of unsure where and what line to put at.  I am thinking lbDue.setText(subTotal);

Comment: It would go in your action handler, since that's where you're calculating the value

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't construct the text fields (tfItem,tfPrice,tfQty).
to solve this add those lines

```
TextField tfItem = new TextField();
TextField tfPrice = new TextField();
TextField tfQty = new TextField();
```

your problem is simple, after calculating the result by applying your formula in the **btAdd** (process button) event handler just add this line at the end of the event handler

```
lbDue.setText( result + "" );
```

this shall solve your issue

Comment: That did it! Thanks a million. I'm still conceptualizing a lot of this feels new to me. One last question, Can I do the same with the reset button?

Comment: Does it require making a new object for radio button?  for example, private Label RadioButton example = new Label(“$0.00”) and then setText.() under the event handler like I did for result ?

Comment: No, any object constructed between **{ }** can be used everywhere in those braces but can't be used out them this is called variables scopes, and to avoid such problems you can define the objects for the whole class like what you did with the radio buttons

Comment: Can I use lbDue.setText( reset + “”);

Comment: also if you want to change any attribute in any object you can do it even if it is shown on the screen, just search for a (set) method for that attribute. as an example, the **setText()**that we used to change the result label text value

Comment: you can use whatever you want whenever you want but only in the variable/object scope **(the curly braces that the object was defined in)**

Comment: Slightly challenging. Thanks , I’ll give it shot.

Comment: To reset a textfield use the clear() method
To reset a radio or checkbox use setSelected(false)
Reset the amount due back to $0.00. How may I put into my code?